# How to call a function belonging to another object in JavaScript (using script.aculo.us)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm creating a new instance of the 'Draggable' object (from the script.aculo.us dragdrop module) inside a function belonging to an object I created. Let's call that object the 'Person' object. Easy enough. However, from inside the 'onEnd' function within the  Draggable object, I need to call another function, getCell(), also belonging to the aforementioned 'Person' object.  Kind of circulatory, I know, but I wish I knew how to do this. Nothing I've tried works. Can it be done? Below is an example heavily edited for brevity but I hope it conveys my intent. I'd be grateful for any insights here. Thanks.

```
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },        
  move: function(p) {
    p = new Draggable(p, {     
     onEnd: function(d) {      
      var pos = getCell(d.element);
      .......
      .......
     }
     .......
     .......
    });
  },
  getCell: function(t) {
    var pos = t.positionedOffset();
    return [(pos.left / 64).floor(), (pos.top /64).floor()];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [Function.bind](http://prototypejs.org/api/function/bind):

```
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },        
  move: function(p) {
    p = new Draggable(p, {     
     onEnd: function(d) {      
      var pos = this.getCell(d.element);
      .......
      .......
     }.bind(this)
     .......
     .......
    });
  },
  getCell: function(t) {
    var pos = t.positionedOffset();
    return [(pos.left / 64).floor(), (pos.top /64).floor()];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
move: function(p) {
    p = new Draggable(p, {     
     onEnd: function(d) {      
      var pos = p.getCell(d.element);
      .......
      .......
     }
     .......
     .......
    });
  },
```

or

```
move: function(p) {
    var getCell = function (el) {
        return p.getCell ( el );
    };

    p = new Draggable(p, {     
     onEnd: function(d) {      
      var pos = getCell(d.element);
      .......
      .......
     }
     .......
     .......
    });
  },
```